# Erro ao criar instalador pelo Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Boa noite pessoal, estou criando um instalador de uma aplicação que usa banco de dados SQLite, na hora de compilar o instalador, exibe um warning informando que é necessário o SQL Server com algumas DLL's, eu não estou entendendo o que está acontecendo..
Segue o erro:

```
O thread 0xbe4 foi fechado com o código 0 (0x0).
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "D:\Fabio\programacao\VisualStudio\Programas\App_Herois_da_Fe\App_Herois_da_Fe\bin\x86\Release\App_Herois_da_Fe.exe". Símbolos carregados.
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt-BR_b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll". O módulo foi criado sem símbolos.
 "App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\mscorlib.resources\v4.0_4.0.0.0_pt-BR_b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.resources.dll". O módulo foi criado sem símbolos.
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "D:\Fabio\programacao\Visual Studio\Programas\App_Herois_da_Fe\App_Herois_da_Fe\bin\x86\Release\System.Data.SQLite.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
Native library pre-loader is trying to load native SQLite library "D:\Fabio\programacao\Visual Studio\Programas\App_Herois_da_Fe\App_Herois_da_Fe\bin\x86\Release\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll"...
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
"App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
O thread 0xdc0 foi fechado com o código 0 (0x0).
O thread 0x25b0 foi fechado com o código 0 (0x0).
O programa "[13644] App_Herois_da_Fe.vshost.exe" foi fechado com o código 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Fabio, essa mensagem do PDB é normal, não são erros, não está relacionado ao seu problema, voce nao tem mais logs? Essa mensagem do trying to load SQLIte que parece estranha, mas não diz que falhou.. 
A proposito, você está rodando o VisualStudio como administrador? As vezes nessas situações de criação de arquivos / setup pode acontecer.

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro não tenho mais logs, sendo que na compilaçao o visual studio faz como se fosse instalar algo do sql server para fazer o instalador e não faz.. ele trava na tal instalaçao do sql server,..... vou tentar fazer a compilaçao como administrador

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro consegui compilar como administrador.. Obrigado, mas agora o problema é outro e vou postar outro topico.. Obrigado